# Create Oracle database query

Tags: oracle

I have the following table (tb1):

[image]

I need to create a query that consist of:

- Select the oldest Date_created having Status 001.
- Should not select a PCR if the same PCR having status 002.

For the table above, this query should return the following table:

[image]

Can anyone help me how to create it?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  If this is `Oracle`, why do I see `MySQL` tag???

Comment: SO is not a free coding service!!!  You create your own query.  If it doesn't work, we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Go learn some SQL.  Just Google SQL tutorial.

Comment: Something like .. `SELECT pcr, min(date_created) from tb1 t1 where not exists ( select null from tbl t2 where t1.pcr = t2.pcr and t2.status = '002' ) group by pcr`.

Comment: Yes thank you TenG, but i can't found how to select all columns as the example above. Can you help me?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will improve my self. the final query:
select q2.id,q2.PCR,q2.status, q2.date_created from (select pcr, min(date_created) date_created from table1 t1 where not exists (select * from 
table1 t2 where t1.pcr = t2.pcr and t2.status = '002') group by pcr) q1 
inner join
(select * from table1) q2
on q1.PCR = q2.PCR and q1.date_created = q2.date_created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final query:
select q2.id,q2.PCR,q2.status, q2.date_created from (select pcr, min(date_created) date_created from table1 t1 where not exists (select * from table1 t2 where t1.pcr = t2.pcr and t2.status = '002') group by pcr) q1 inner join (select * from table1) q2 on q1.PCR = q2.PCR and q1.date_created = q2.date_created